# How can I make this code display a text message if no results were fetched from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{    
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><p>{$row['tittel']}</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><textarea rows='1' cols='64' style='no-resize;'>{$row['video']}</textarea></td>"; 
echo "<td><form method='GET' action='delete.php'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_id' value='{$row['id']}'/>"; 
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete' style='margin-bottom: 30px;'>";
echo "</form></td>";    
echo "</tr>";
}
```

It may be basic stuff, but I'm still learning.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: !!! MYSQL_ functions are deprecated! please use mysqli or PDO_mysql instead !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($retval)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {  ...  } 
} else {
    echo 'no rows';
}
```

***P.S.:*** [`php_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`php_mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`php_pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis after `$retval`.  Beware that `mysql_num_rows()` will return `FALSE` if it failed, so your `else` condition may arise not only when there are no rows.

Comment: Thank you, this works!
Also, thanks for the heads up about php_mysql being deprecated.

Comment: @Raymond Holthe good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($retval) != 0) {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {    
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td><p>{$row['tittel']}</p></td>";
       echo "</tr>";
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td><textarea rows='1' cols='64' style='no-resize;'>{$row['video']}</textarea></td>"; 
       echo "<td><form method='GET' action='delete.php'>";
       echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_id' value='{$row['id']}'/>"; 
       echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete' style='margin-bottom: 30px;'>";
       echo "</form></td>";    
       echo "</tr>";
    }
 } else {
    //Your message here
 }
```